# Google Visualization library not loading - syntax error

Tags: charts, google-visualization, syntax-error

I am trying to build a dashboard of charts as a Google UiApp and am having problems loading the necessary library.  I am getting a syntext error on line 8, which is the "google.load('visualization', ..." line.  I am literally copying and pasting the example from the tutorial and that line keeps coming up as an error. Any ideas?  I'm pretty new to this, just trying to scrape together a demo by following the directions here: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs

```
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API library and the piechart library.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart', 'piechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  // insert charts here

</script>
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, Google UiApp uses Apps Script, not javascript, so you need to use the Apps Script implemenetation of the Visualization API.  [Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/?csw=1)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use it, which works for me (example on: http://jsfiddle.net/UT2G7/):

```
google.load('visualization','1.0',{'packages':['corechart']});
```